# Leave last/newest records in table by a combination of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I leave one record (last/newest) for each resource_owner_id and scopes combination and remove other records?

For example, for resource_owner_id=3 and scopes=driver it should be only record with id=1357.resource_owner_id=5 and scopes=driver - with id=1034

I know that I can use `.ids`, after that get all records by id and scope (scopes are enum - 'driver' and 'passenger'), after that use `.pop` and remove all remaining records.

Maybe there is a more elegant solution?

[image]

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=762a4b8297dab746c8504907c5a2d188)

ActiveRecord version:

```
Model.select("DISTINCT ON(resource_owner_id, scopes) *")
     .order("resource_owner_id, scopes, id")
```

Read more about `DISTINCT ON` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564).

Comment: Thanks! But I need leave in table this records and remove all other records. Should I just add this line`Model.where.not(id:@models.map(&:id)).destroy_all`?

Comment: Ah, I thought that by remove you mean remove them from the returned records. Yes, that would work, depending on what callbacks you have, you might consider `delete_all` as it would be much faster.